# On search for VIM Modifications

Tags: macos, vim, editor

I'm on the search to style vim like this screenshot. Especially the status bar on the bottom of the Interface with the Git Breadcump.
Do anyone know the used Plugins..?

[image: VIM Gui]

I hope yo can Help me.

Answer (score 2):

[vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) + [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugins and [Molokai Color Scheme](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai).

vim-airline features:

- Tiny core written with extensibility in mind (open/closed principle).
- Integrates with a variety of plugins, including: vim-bufferline, fugitive, unite, ctrlp, minibufexpl, gundo, undotree, nerdtree, tagbar, vim-gitgutter, vim-signify, quickfixsigns, syntastic, eclim, lawrencium, virtualenv, tmuxline, taboo.vim, ctrlspace and more.
- Looks good with regular fonts and provides configuration points so you can use unicode or powerline symbols.
- Optimized for speed; it loads in under a millisecond.
- Extensive suite of themes for popular color schemes including solarized (dark and light), tomorrow (all variants), base16 (all variants), molokai, jellybeans and others; have a look at the screenshots in the wiki.

Comment: The color scheme doesn't look like molokai.